# How can I debug javascript and css on safari for iPad (Can I use something like firebug on iPad)?

Tags: javascript, css, ipad, safari, firebug

I am developing an iPad version for my site and I have difficulties debugging javascript and css on ipad. Is there any easy way to do this? can I use something like firebug on iPad?

Comment: [weinre](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nL6xey13fE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at JS Console http://jsconsole.com/.

Here's a nice intro video to get started http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BEo8oJYey-M